# Forge api translating .fbx to SVF2 doesnt work and translates only to SVF

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative

I am using forge-apis package on Node.js and I want to translate a .fbx file in SVF2. When I do so and load the model, size and GPU memory used is the same as normal translate to SVF and when I check viewer.model.isSVF2() it return false.

```
const {
DerivativesApi,
JobPayload,
JobPayloadInput,
JobPayloadOutput,
JobSvfOutputPayload} = require('forge-apis');
```

and

```
router.post('/jobs', async (req, res, next) => {
const xAdsForce = (req.body.xAdsForce === true);
let job = new JobPayload();
job.input = new JobPayloadInput();
job.input.urn = req.body.objectName;
if(req.body.rootFilename && req.body.compressedUrn) {
    job.input.rootFilename = req.body.rootFilename;
    job.input.compressedUrn = req.body.compressedUrn;
}

job.output = new JobPayloadOutput([
    new JobSvfOutputPayload()
]);
job.output.formats[0].type = 'svf2' ;
job.output.formats[0].views = ['2d', '3d'];
try {
    // Submit a translation job using [DerivativesApi](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client/blob/master/docs/DerivativesApi.md#translate).
    const result = await new DerivativesApi().translate(job, { xAdsForce: xAdsForce }, req.oauth_client, req.oauth_token);
    res.status(200).end();
} catch(err) {
    next(err);
}});
```

How can I handle this problem? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you end up with an answer to this ever?  I'm having the same issue from .DWG's to SVF2.  Same model, size, gpu memory, and isSVF2() returns false.

Comment: @MattH in my case  the file contained only one surface, so there were basically no difference between SVF and SVF2. But still I believe the translation to SVF2 should have happened.