# Autodesk Forge - Do any IDs persist when translating a new source file with minor changes?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

**Background**

We currently use AutoDesk Forge to display 2D models of floor plans.  Users have the ability to upload new floor plans (which uploads to OSS, then translates the file) to replace existing ones, that may include new objects in the room, or slightly different positioning of existing objects.  Currently, we grab certain object dbId's via `viewer.getSelection()` to "bind" (using the term loosely here) some external data to the object and perform certain interactions within our web app.  We are using `.DWG` files.

**Issue**

When uploading a new floor plan that removes an object, it shifts dbId's of other objects, and our external binding is then inaccurate.

**Question**

• Are there any IDs that persist between the uploads/translations?

*We *do not* maintain control of the .dwg files prior to their upload, so adding attributes on the drawing before it's translated likely won't be viable for our particular case - but if that's the best (or only) approach, I would like to know to propose it as a possible solution to my team.

**Example**

Let's say there's a simple square room with 5 chairs, and it's rendered and visible in the viewer since it's been uploaded as room1 (object key).  We identify 3 chairs by their dbIds and save that, so a user can jump right to the object in question, and we put a label on it.  Then someone comes along and *removes* one of the chairs, uploads/translates the document again with the same object key.  Now, the dbIds are changed and assigned to different chairs and as a result.  Question is, is there something other than dbId that persists between the different renderings?  Or, is there something that I haven't considered that would be a better approach of keeping the binding accurate between uploads?

EDIT: Same scenario happens with element ID's.  An interesting finding is the element ID and dbId are tightly coupled (meaning if Object A's dbId is 3 and element ID is 6E, then a deletion happens, a new object will have 3 and 6E respectively).  Also, I believe the designers creating the AutoCAD files are making these as polylines, if that makes a difference

**Contingency Plan**

If there's not an ID of some sort that persists, I'm considering storing the coordinates of the object we want to bind to, and later *find* the closest object to those x/y/z coords.  Is that a possibility, to find an object close to or overlapping xyz?

Answer (score 1):

Use external id.
Useful blog: https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/get-dbid-externalid

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't work.  We tested swapping our application over to use the external ID and performed tests.  When adding new objects or moving existing objects, all IDs remained the same.  When we deleted an object, it shifted IDs (both external id and dbId) to other objects.  Oddly enough, the pairing of dbId to external id stayed the same (so dbId of 39677 and external Id of 23293 remained tied together, but pointed to a different object after deleting something from the drawing).

Comment: Ok, I’ll check again and get back to you.

Comment: I edited the question to include the file type we are uploading (.dwg).  Looks like your suggestion would work for revits and such, so still +1 for the suggestion as is!

Comment: Thanks for updating, will check for dwg files.

Comment: When you replace and translate it again, are you using x-ads-force: true header?
This is a must if you're translating a modified file a second time. In our test, the external id from two modified Dwg files was not changed.

Comment: Yes.  I do have x-ads-force set to true.  In our tests, it requires deleting an object for it to rearrange ID assignments.  We can move and add objects without the issue, but deleting an object causes the issue.

Comment: Another useful bit of info may be we are using SVF and not SVF2.  Our attempts at SVF2 failed similar to the following request for help: 
 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70666318/forge-api-translating-fbx-to-svf2-doesnt-work-and-translates-only-to-svf

Comment: Hi MAtt, Are you still facing the issue? I believe we had a zoom call? Anyways, we can have a call in case you need more help. Please book on https://calendly.com/autodeskforge