# AutoDesk Forge Viewer dbId / externalId change without interaction

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer, autodesk-model-derivative

We're having an intermittent issue that just started two weeks ago, where the `externalId` and `dbId` are being reassigned over the weekend to different objects without any user interaction (no new file upload or translation job occurred between Friday and Monday, but the objects were essentially given new dbIds and externalIds between viewing on Friday and Monday).

This first happened between 4/1/2022 and 4/4/2022.  I thought it was our users that didn't follow the guidelines we implemented.
It happened again between 4/8/2022 and 4/11/2022 to a different autocad.

I'm wondering what causes the `dbId` & `externalId` to be assigned to specific objects when viewed in the autodesk viewer?  I assumed that the only thing that would cause different `dbIds` or `externalIds` is the translation job.  Is this an inaccurate understanding?  Also, is there any type of audit history to see all occurrences of when an autocad file was uploaded/translated?

*Reference my original issue (***still unresolved***, I just implemented the workaround suggested):  [Autodesk Forge - Do any IDs persist when translating a new source file with minor changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71227809/autodesk-forge-do-any-ids-persist-when-translating-a-new-source-file-with-mino/71232557?noredirect=1#comment126061775_71232557)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once an SVF (or an SVF2) output is generated, its dbIDs and externalIDs are baked and cannot change. If you're seeing the dbIDs changing, this could be happening because:

- The model is being re-translated (perhaps accidentally?)
- You are switching between SVF1 and SVF2 outputs of the same model

If you could share the URN of one of the models where you noticed this change, and a rough timeframe where this change occurred, we could check our logs to see whether the model has been re-translated.

Also, do you know whether you're loading SVF1 or SVF2 models?

Comment: Primarily SVF1's, but only because I'm running into issues with SVF2's.  I had a meeting with Varun to try to work through it, but need to send him some more info.  It's possible I was testing SVF2's which caused the issue.  The URN is below for the second time, between 4/8/22 and 4/11/2022.

`dXJuOmFkc2sub2JqZWN0czpvcy5vYmplY3Q6dW5xMTlkYWFlMDY2NDAxNGIwYjkxZWQxYmIyZmIzMjcvNTAxMjdFNDItQjRCNi1FQzExLTk4M0YtMDAwRDNBNUQwRTU3LmR3Zw`

Comment: Our engineering team checked the logs, and they found that there were two `POST job` requests made to this URN, one on April 4, at approx 4:50:20, and another one on April 4, at approx 11:27:36. Please check your implementation and make sure that you're not accidentally triggering the 2nd translation. This could be the reason why you're seeing different dbids/externalids.

Comment: Thank you for checking into this and getting back to me.  I'll dig into why it could have run at those times.  I appreciate the help!

Comment: What time zone were those time stamps for?

Comment: Good question :D I _think_ those should be in UTC.